# Data Node and Node Manager is not starting in pseudo-cluster mode(Apache Hadoop)

Tags: apache, hadoop

The Data Node and Node Manager is not starting in pseudo-cluster mode (Apache Hadoop).

Seeing this error in the log file:

```
***2017-08-22 17:15:08,403 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Unexpected error starting NodeStatusUpdater
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: NodeManager from  archit doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.***

    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:543)
2017-08-22 17:15:08,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl failed in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "`ResourceManager: NodeManager from archit doesn't satisfy minimum allocations`" error is seen when node on which node manager is being started does not have enough resources w.r.t `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` and `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` configurations.

Reduce values of `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` and `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` then restart yarn.

Comment: How to reduce the values of yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores and yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb can you pls guide me i am beginer to hadoop

Comment: What are values of parameter currently and what is capacity of cluster node ?