# Node manager stops running after few momentes

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hadoop2, bigdata

Getting the below error

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Unexpected error starting NodeStatusUpdater
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: NodeManager from ubuntu-VirtualBox doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.

Comment: You are hitting issue similar to one reported at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879190/data-node-and-node-manager-is-not-starting-in-pseudocluster-modeapache-hadoop/45879464#45879464 . I have answered it , please check.

Comment: How to reduce the values of yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores and yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb.    I am a beginer and just installed the hadoop and testing jps command first time then seeing that all 6 resources are running and hit the jps second time then seeing node manger is missing.

Comment: @Shubhangi  
could you please suggest me how to resolve the same.